# Amazon Cloudfront settings to reduce waiting time

Tags: cdn, amazon-cloudfront

UPDATE: This was my mistake, see my comment the below. Now Cloudfront works great with new settings.

Sometimes dns waits 600ms and than it will wait another half second which makes 90kb file waiting more than 1 second. Sometimes pingdom wait time shows even 1 second. If I try another test, it will go sometimes to 90ms all together.

I understand that first request will take more time because cloudfront needs first to take file from our server. I set cache time to 86400 s which means if it should get file from cache for whole 24 hours. But if I try pingdom just 2 hours after first test it will go again very slow.

The below are my results and settings. Am I missing something?
[image]

Comment: I think it was my dummy mistake :). It is set to be Use Origin Cache Headers instead of Customize.

Comment: I'd love to know what website you used to run those tests from different locations.

Comment: It looks like he used Pingdom, which is an amazing test tool.

Comment: I apologize I didn't see your question before. Yes this was Pingdom.

Answer (score -2):

Most of the cases its the DNS that makes the delay because amazon is really scalable.

I had similar issues with my ISP and was able to resolve its quickly by changing the DNS servers.

Try changing your DNS to Google DNS
IP V4
     8.8.8.8
     8.8.4.4

IP V6

```
2001:4860:4860::8888
2001:4860:4860::8844
```

[Google Public Dns Documentation](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using)

Or use OPEN DNS

```
208.67.220.220
208.67.222.222
```

[OPEN DNS Documentation](https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/sections/206253647)

Answer (score -3):

CloudFront is not only scalable, it also eliminates bottlenecks, but aims to speed it up.
AWS CloudFront is a service with low latency and fast transfer rates.

Here are some of the symptoms that may be slower when using CloudFront.
(This includes most problems.)

1. The requesting Edge may be receiving a large number of requests.
2. The edge server closest to the client may be farther than the web host server.
   (Geographic delay)
3. DNS lookups can be delayed.
4. There is not much of this possibility, but make sure the x-edge is in the "View in cloud front" state.
   Cache may be missing.

Detailed troubleshooting is difficult because you do not know what the test is or what the condition is.
If logging is enabled, further troubleshooting is possible.
It is generally recommended to enable logging.

If you have any questions, please feel free to ask!
thank you.